# Are iMessage encryption keys sent to all listed devices even if they're broken?

Tags: iphone, encryption

Are iMessage encyption keys sent to all authenticated devices listed under Apple ID, even if the device isn't powered on and is broken?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to send a key to a device that isn’t powered on, and/or not online. The device must “sign-in” with Apples servers before any data, such as a key, is transferred.

Comment: Ok.  But say you have a broken device listed, but not powered on, and then you turn that device on, would that device then receive the encryption key?

Comment: The encryption key for what exactly? Normally iMessage does not send encryption keys to devices by itself?

Comment: The encryption key for an iMessage thread.... I've read that Apple sends encryption keys to each of your devices using iMessage. Does that include all devices listed in your AppleID that uses iMessage?  Even if the device hasn't been recently used?

Comment: It's the other way around. For that purpose it is the device that sends it keys to Apple's servers.